# How should I handle data needed for a package?

Tags: python, io, package

I have a python package that requires a data file to work.
At the moment I am just using `open("<filename>",'r')` to read the data from it.

However, the success of this is dependent on the current directory. I feel there is some way I should be able to tell python to look for a file in a directory relative to the package source, rather than relative to the file using the package.

For JVM languages there is a "resource" directory, and `Class.getResource` which works very well. Is there some equivalent for python? If not, what is the standard way of dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A module typically has a `__file__` property, to tell where the package originates from. For instance for `re`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.__file__
'/usr/lib/python3.5/re.py'
>>> os.path.dirname(re.__file__)
'/usr/lib/python3.5'
```

or for `flask`:

```
>>> import flask
>>> flask.__file__
'/home/foo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/__init__.py'
>>> os.path.dirname(flask.__file__)
'/home/foo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask'
```

You can then use `os.path.dirname` to obtain the directory, and use `os.path.join` to join the path together with the new filename.

So say you want to load a file relatively to the `re` package, you can use:

```
import re
import os

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(re.__file__),'foo.data'),'r') as f:
#                                                    ^ relative pathname
    pass
```

With `'foo.data'` here a file *relative* to the `re` package file.

Comment: That seems to have worked. One thing, is using the forwards slash in`'../foo.data'` strictly correct? path.join seems to make something like '\\a\\b\\../foo.data' on my windows machine, which it can deal with, but I can imagine the other way round is not so good.

Comment: @Lucas: good point. I'm getting a bit too much used to Linux. So better be safe than sorry.